# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in DJI SDK

Tags: android, kotlin, dji-sdk

I'm getting `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void` causing an app crash when calling a DJI SDK library function. In my case I'm calling `FlyZoneManager.getInstance().downloadFlyZoneLicensesFromServer()`. The specific error is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void dji.csdk.fscore.jni.unlock.JNIFSUnlockManager.native_fetchServerLicense(dji.component.flysafe.listener.JNIUnlockCommonCallbacks$JNIUnlockCommonCallbackWith) (tried Java_dji_csdk_fscore_jni_unlock_JNIFSUnlockManager_native_1fetchServerLicense and Java_dji_csdk_fscore_jni_unlock_JNIFSUnlockManager_native_1fetchServerLicense__Ldji_component_flysafe_listener_JNIUnlockCommonCallbacks_00024JNIUnlockCommonCallbackWith_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is not being registered properly - Make sure to call `SDKManager.getInstance().registerApp()` first as this is somehow related to the native library linking. Nothing in the [documentation](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference-v5/android-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html?search=register&i=0&#isdkmanager_registerapp_inline) or the error message suggests this relation but making sure this call was actually happening fixed this for me after hours of hair pulling.

Example code:

```kt
SDKManager.getInstance().init(applicationContext, object : SDKManagerCallback {
    override fun onInitProcess(event: DJISDKInitEvent?, totalProcess: Int) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onInitProcess: ")
        if (event == DJISDKInitEvent.INITIALIZE_COMPLETE) {
            SDKManager.getInstance().registerApp()
        }
    }
    // Implement other callbacks
}
```